# Idiomatic Ruby - Assign variable only if not nil without using `if`

Tags: ruby

I have a whole bunch of lines like this

```
api_data[:foo] = foo if foo
api_data[:bar] = bar if bar
api_data[:batz] = batz if batz
```

I want a terse, idiomatic way to assign only if !nil.

Thanks

Comment: why do you not want to use `if`?

Comment: What about `false`? Your code doesn't match your description.

Comment: `api_data[:foo] = foo unless foo.nil?`?

Comment: What you have is different than what you want if `foo` can equal `false`. There are four possibilities for `foo`: `foo` equals `nil`, `foo`  equals `false`, `foo` equals a (truthy) value other than `nil` and `false` and `foo` has not been defined. Do you want to consider all four possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to assign values that are non-`nil`:

```
api_data.merge!(
  {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar,
    bart: barts
  }.reject { |_,v|v.nil? }
)
```

This is a little messy, so you might want to make an extension to the Hash class that ignores `nil` assignments:

```
class PickyHash < Hash
  def []=(k,v)
    return if (v.nil?)
    super
  end
end
```

Then:

```
api_data = PickyHash.new
api_data[:foo] = 'foo'
api_data[:foo] = nil

api_data
#> {:foo=>"foo"}
```

Comment: `api_data[:foo] ||= foo` will assign only if `api_data[:foo]` evaluates to false (i.e. nil or false), which does not seem to answer the question

Comment: @harald Thanks. Updated accordingly.

Comment: At your current rate you should roll the zeroes after about seven sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

```
api_data[:foo] = foo
api_data[:bar] = bar
api_data[:batz] = batz

api_data.reject! { |_, value| value.nil? }
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say that I like this solution, but anyway:

```
Hash[[:foo, :bar, :baz].find_all { |var| eval var.to_s }.map { |var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
["foo", "bar", "batz"].each do |v|
    eval(v).tap {|val| api_data[v.to_sym] = val if val }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one using [`Array#compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) and [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
[foo, bar, batz].compact.each_with_object(api_data) {|elem, acc| acc.merge!({elem => elem})}
```

Where `[foo, bar, batz].compact` returns the input array eliminating `nil`, and you're merging each non-nil element from the input array to `api_data` hash passed in as the initial value to `each_with_object`.

Comment: I just saw this! wondering why this answer was downvoted! Please feel free to provide any feedback.